# Buttons move around when resizing window

Tags: html, css

Everything on my page centers horizontally, including my buttons. However - when I resize my window, the buttons move vertically and off the page. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rjord00r/utjhyckt/

```
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 380px;
}


.buttons button {
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just recreated this on my computer and it is doing exactly as it should, but I do not have your images files so your issue could be deriving from that.

Comment: I re-did the jsfiddle link to reflect my locally hosted image. http://jsfiddle.net/rjord00r/utjhyckt/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/utjhyckt/1/. I move all the elements into the same parent that way your margins were not relative the body itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of unnecessary positioning, margins and elements in your example. To be able to achieve what I think you're after, I've had to change a few things.

See new [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9cqmhw20/6/) here.

Here's a summary of the changes : -

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="centered">
    <img class="logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
    <form class="search-bar">
       <input type="text" class="search">
       <div id="icon">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l5S4LZ2.png" />
        </div>
        </form>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button type="button">Google Search</button>
      <button type="button">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 272px;
}

.search {
  width: 400px;
  height: 28px;
}

.search-bar {
  position: relative;
}

#icon img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 28px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 3px;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

NOTE - I've removed anything from the example that I haven't changed.

Answer (score 0):

**This for you:**

```css
.searchBox{ 
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -92px;
  margin-left: -225px;
  width: 450px;
  text-align:center;
}

.logo {
  width: 272px;
}


.search {
  width: 450px;
  height: 28px;
  margin:15px 0px;
}

.search-bar{
  position:relative;
}

#icon img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 28px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 18px;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: blue;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons button {
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchBox">
  <div class="centered">
    <img class="logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="search">
      <div id="icon">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/l5S4LZ2.png" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button">Google Search</button>
    <button type="button">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
  </div>
</div>
```